# How to rename WordPress plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I have already crated a plugin for WordPress and I was wondering If it is possible to change its' name.

ie: Lets say I have the plugin that It's definition looks like that

```
/*
Plugin Name: Current plugin name
Plugin URI: http://www.plugin.url
Description: Some description about that plugin
Author: The author name
Version: 1.0.0
Author URI: http://www.author.url
*/
```

Is it posible to create a new plugin version that will looks like that:

```
/*
Plugin Name: New plugin name
Plugin URI: http://www.plugin.url
Description: Some description about that plugin
Author: The author name
Version: 2.0.0
Author URI: http://www.author.url
*/
```

*Focus on plugin name*

And after that, when the plugin will be installed from the WordPress repository, will that affect the plugin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, you are on correct track, but you need to change name before installing plugin.

Comment: Are you talking about the installation of the new plugin ?

Comment: you can copy/paste any plugin and rename that plugin. if you change plugin definition then it will easy to identify updated plugin in administrator area. you can not install plugin with same name in WP because plugin share common directory. if you copy/paste any existing plugin then you need to change folder name. change of plugin definition it's advisable.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the name inside your plugin file in the 'Plugin Name' field. This will change the display in the UI.

However, you cannot change the URL for the plugin on Wordpress.org.

Answer (score 0):

I tried by changing :

```
/*
Plugin Name: My new name
*/
```

but it didn't work. Then I tried by changing the name in readme.txt :

```
/*
=== My new name ===
*/
```

And it worked for me !

Comment: You can always rename those however, if it's your own plugin you should update the plugin in the wordpress repository. Other people will then see the new settings/name.

Comment: Hey, I have a published plugin and I want to change its name. You said that changing the name in the readme.txt works, but do you know what happens to the users that already installed it? will it continue to update as normal?

Comment: hi @GermánLena have you figured what happens with users who have already installed this plugin. Does they get plugin update notifications or not ?

Comment: @Anand There is no problem with that since the plugin slug keeps the same.